# const object for copy constructor

Tags: constants, copy-constructor

I am reading about copy constructor. 
can any body tell me what is happening in the below statement

```
class Base {
public:
Base() {cout << "Base constructor";}
Base(const Base& a) {cout << "copy constructor with const arg";}
Base(Base& a) {cout << "copy constructor with non-const arg"; return a;}
const Base& operator=(Base &a) {cout << "assignment operator with non-const arg"; return a;}
}

void main()
{
    Base a;
    Base b = Base(); // This is neither calling copy constructor nor assignment operator.
}
```

Please tell me what is happening at "Base b = Base()" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Copy constructor will be called in three casess:

```
When an object is returned by value 
When an object is passed (to a function) by value as an argument 
When an object is thrown 
When an object is caught 
When an object is placed in a brace-enclosed initializer list
```

assignment opertator will be called when below:

```
B b;
b=a;
```

so your statement:

```
Base b = Base();
```

does not suit any of the above.

Comment: Then what is happening here. The Base() is creating a temp object, isn't that assigning to b?